# WebSocket connection lost

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, websocket-sharp

I'm developing a windows desktop application WebSocket client, I use [WebSocket-Sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) nuget to connect to the server.

My problem is when the connection is Idle for some time, my client will not send any `pong` responses to server `ping` requests, by checking Fiddler (screenshot below) you can see that third server `ping` request always will hang and no response will be sent.

[image]

I try to send `ping` requests from my client to server every 10 seconds (rather than waiting server to send `ping` every 20 seconds), by checking Fiddler I can see that my client is sending `ping` requests to server and server response properly, but actually after a small period of Idle time (around 30 seconds) my client `ping` requests result is `False` (which mean they failed).

**Update 1:**
I forget to mention that when I test server using "Simple Web Socket Client" Chrome extension it is working fine with no issues.

My questions are:

- Does anybody know how I can troubleshoot or solve thisproblem in websocket-sharp nuget?
- Do you recommend any other nuget package or should I build my cleint from scratch rather than depending on third-party libraries?

Comment: Try two things 1) use cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give status on connection to see if the connection closed 2) Check Fiddler for FIN which indicates the connection closed.  The server may be closing connection when idle so you may need to enable the Keep-Alive when client connects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will check your recommendations and let you know the result, but I forget to mention in the question that when I try to connect to same server using "Simple Web Socket client" Chrome browser extension it is working fine.

Comment: I perform steps you mentioned and found the following. 1) connection state is LISTENING. 2) by checking Fiddler logs I found the following 2 errors 
- 12:37:27:2535 [WebSocket #1904] Read from Server returned error: 0
- 12:37:27:2535 [WebSocket #1904] Read from Client failed... Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It looks like the server is listening but the client connection failed.  A webconnection uses TCP as transport layer so every web connection also has a TCP.  TCP has max size of 1500 bytes so for every http message you will see multiple TCP messages.  A server can have multiple clients connect so I can't tell if the client is really connect.  I would sniffer the Chrome Connection and see what headers are being used.  I suspect you need to add the Chrome headers to your http request.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers that were helpful in troubleshooting the problem. it seems that I was use a cloned version from WebSocket-Sharp, i replace dlls from official github site and all issues had been resolved. It's my mistake I had to be more concentrated.